# Agile Accelerator Work Item field

Tags: administration

In the *Agile Accelerator* app, on the Work object, I removed the **"Description"** field to replace it with the **"Details and Steps to Reproduce"** field on all work item page layouts.

However, when I am creating a new work item, it is still showing the **"Description"** field and the **"Details and Steps to Reproduce"** field is not visible. (See below)

[image]

When I am done creating the work item, the **"Description"** field is not showing like it should and the **"Details and Steps to Reproduce"** is visible.

[image]

The **"Details and Steps to Reproduce"** is a Rich Text Area field.

[image]

Any idea how to resolve this so I can only see the **"Details and Steps to Reproduce"** field.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that  the new button for `Work` object is not opening up the normal page layout, but a custom page (visualforce page) set by the package. Hence, why it's not respecting your changes to the page layout.

You can see that `New` and `Edit` are overridden by the package

`Setup --> Object Manager --> Work --> Buttons, Links, and Actions --> New`

You can choose to use the standard page instead (but this will change the UI).

[image]

That will allow you to control what displays as you're suggesting through the page layout.